# Bash Regex multiple optional captures

Tags: regex, wordpress, bash

I'm trying to get information out of wordpress plugins, the plugin name and the version.

I'm finding that the line I'm looking for could be `Plugin Name:`,  `Plugin Name:`,    `Plugin Name:` , or  `* Plugin Name:` or variations of space. Since the line I"m looking for is in the comments part, it may also include the *

I've gotten as far as getting the whitespace optional, I think, but i can't figure out capturing the * with space around it.

```
grep "^\s*Plugin Name:" $files
```

which is working for most of the plugins but not all, since some have other characters to watch out for.

I've tried

```
(\s*)?|( \* )?  
[ *]|[ \* ]? 
( *| \* )?
```

but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around stringing it all together.

Edit:
Using

```
grep -E '^\s*\*?\s*Plugin Name:' $files
```

will find everything, but two of the plugins in this case now, that have `* Plugin Name:` will print out an entirely different directory in addition to the correct information.

$plugPath is the wordpress plugins folder - /wp-content/plugins

```
folders=`find $plugPath -maxdepth 1 -type d`
for plugin_folder in $folders
do
    echo $plugin_folder
    files=`find $plugin_folder -maxdepth 1 -name "*.php"`

    n=`grep -hE '^\s*\*?\s*Plugin Name:' $files`
    v=`grep -hE '^\s*\*?\s*Version:' $files`
    echo " -- "$n
    echo " -- "$v
done
```

Result I'm expecting:

```
/home/test/accounts/account-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/flexible-recent-posts
 -- Plugin Name: Flexible Recent Posts
 -- Version: 1.0.4
```

Example that is working:

```
Plugin Name: Flexible Recent Posts
Plugin URI: http://steelrat.info/
Description: Displays recent posts using flexible template system.
Version: 1.0.4
Author: SteelRat
```

Where it's screwing up:

```
/home/test/accounts/account-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/portfolio-post-type
 --  2015.11.13-AccountInfo.log.csv accounts bin Desktop Documents Downloads latest.tar.gz Music Pictures Public Templates test-info.log.csv Videos wordpress Plugin Name: Portfolio Post Type
 --  2015.11.13-AccountInfo.log.csv accounts bin Desktop Documents Downloads latest.tar.gz Music Pictures Public Templates test-info.log.csv Videos wordpress Version: 0.9.1
```

The file it finds these in is like:

```
 * Plugin Name: Portfolio Post Type
 * Plugin URI:  http://wptheming.com/portfolio-post-type/
 * Description: Enables a portfolio post type and taxonomies.
 * Version:     0.9.1
```

Comment: Can't you just use `^\s*\*\s*Plugin Name:`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: By the way, if your `*` must be space-wrapped: `^\s*\( \* \)\?\s*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple:

```
grep "Plugin Name:"
```

is not enough?

**UPDATE**

Then try this version:

```
grep -E '^\s*[*]?\s*Plugin Name:'
```

Or an equivalent:

```
grep -E '^\s*\*?\s*Plugin Name:'
```

**UPDATE 2**

Probably the loop in the updated question suffer the *non-adequately-quoted-filename* syndrome. I suggest a find one-liner to obtain almost the same functionality:

```
find "${WORDPRESS_PLUGIN_DIR}" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -iname "*.php" -exec grep -E '^\s*\*?\s*(Plugin Name|Version):' {} \;
```

Comment: because I am getting returns like this on some plugins: assets features grunt Gruntfile.js info.txt languages _modd README.md rebrand.gif  Plugin Name: Portfolio Post Type

Comment: @ooklah: i understand, try the updated version of the regex

Comment: two plugins that have the * in them still include all the extra stuff in the first comment, but it does eventually include the correct information. Which is better then I started with which was just empty

Comment: @ooklah: update the question reporting the offending lines, i'll fix the regex to remove them

Comment: I updated the question, it seems like when it finds one plugin with * in it, it will go grab the home directory it's in or one of the other plugins and add it to the grep. When I reopened my terminal, instead of a plugin it now was displaying my home directory.

Comment: @ooklah: sorry, it's not clear to me how these lines are composed neither if you want to match these lines or not (extracting some specific section). If is not a problem, try to explain as clearly as possible again the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95493/discussion-between-ooklah-and-gsusrecovery).

Answer (score 0):

This catches everything, including spaces prior, plus a single space past `Plugin Name:`

```
grep -G "^.*Plugin Name:\s" $files
```